# Which wifi device to use

Tags: wireless-networking

I've a wireless router on my ground floor.

And my system is in first floor and for its connection I'm using a wifi adapter, which works fine.

But on first floor, the connectivity on phones and tablets in week and breaks down every now and then.

Which device should I use on first floor to get connectivity on all devices there?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the WiFi at some other level than your devices is a bad idea. The coverage will be poor as the *radio waves are emitted parallel to the length of the antenna.*

However you can improve on this situation

1. **Adjust your antenna,** if you do most of your networking at the upper
   floor, **make the antenna parallel to the ground** instead of keeping it
   perpendicular.
2. **Use a Wi-Fi Repeater,** just get any old or budget Wi-Fi router and
   set it on the "repeater/bridge" setting, this will greatly improve
   the signal. **(YOUR ANSWER)**
3. **Find the Right Wireless Channel,** If you have neighbours, their
   routers may be interfering with yours and causing the signal to
   degrade. Wireless routers can operate on a number of different
   channels, and you want yours on a channel with as little
   interference as possible. Use a tool like Wi-Fi Stumbler or [Wi-Fi
   Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=en) for android.
4. **Increase Wi-Fi Range with DIY Tricks,** make custom (cheap) antennas.
   The Windsurfer tin foil hack works well for me. You may even buy a high dB anteena but that will cost you something and will work only if you have a detachable antenna.
5. **Use a Custom Firmware for your router** such as [Gargoyole Router
   management](http://www.gargoyle-router.com/) or [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) to **overclock** the broadcasting signal *(be
   careful with this one)*
6. **Find your WiFi Sweet Spot**, make a WiFi strength Map of your house using free tools like [Ekahu WiFIMapper](http://www.ekahau.com/wifidesign/ekahau-heatmapper)
7. If none of the above satisfies you, move your router.

Comment: The best solution it to add additional access points that are wired to the router. (You can use wireless routers as access points if you disable their DHCP server and don't use the WAN port.)

Comment: agreed, second point. Here's an example [How To Setup a 2nd Router as an Access Point & Extend Your Wireless Network](http://www.geektonic.com/2007/06/how-to-setup-2nd-router-as-access-point.html)

Comment: WiFi repeaters increase range but cost bandwidth and don't handle non-standard networking setups very well (due to MAC NAT). Adding an additional access point is a much better solution.

Comment: Can you please provide a link of an example setup?

Comment: It's pretty simple. You set both devices to the same SSID, encryption mode, and key, but different channels. You connect a LAN port on one to a LAN port on the other. Make sure to disable DHCP on the access point.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so basically a second router will act as an access point. Do the main router and access point router needs to be connected physically via LAN cable? Because I the access point router will be on another floor and I dont have cable that spans 2 floors.

Comment: In the method I'm suggesting, yes they do. Making an Ethernet cable is simple. If you care about network quality, it's what you really want to do.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz actually that is the thing I'm avoiding. So would you suggest wifi repeater otherwise?

Comment: I do not ever recommend using WiFi "repeaters". If you're talking about real WDS, yes, that's fine. I've seen too many problems caused by fake WiFi "repeaters" that use NAT hacks to "sort of bridge" multiple devices to a single WiFi client connection to ever recommend such things. WiFi *cannot* be repeated (unless WDS is configured on both ends).